# How do induction on a recursive defined function?

Tags: analysis

I made a mistake on some homework, because I didn't prove by induction, but I am lost upon how to prove this my induction.

How I understand in induction:

1. Show base case (n=1) is true
2. Assume n case is true
3. Show that n+1 case is true.

How do I apply that to show:

$x_1 > 3$ and $x_{n+1} = 2+\sqrt{x_n -2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ then $x = 3$.

I showed that $x = 2$ or $x=3$ and showed that $x_{n+1} \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ and said by the comparison theorem that it was bounded.  But my professor said I should have used induction.

I am lost upon how to apply induction to this problem because I don't know how to do the base case step.  $x_0$ is not defined and $x_1 > 3$ is all that is given.

> I am to use induction to show that $x_{n+1} < x_n$

Don't worry, I already got a poor grade on this problem.

Comment: And what is the question? What has induction to prove?

Comment: fixed it. To show that $x_{n+1} < x_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to first show by induction that $x_n>3$ for all $n$:

We already have the base case.  And then, if $x_n>3$, we obtain $x_{n+1}=2+\sqrt{x_n-2}>2+\sqrt{3-2}=3$.

From this we have $x_{n}-2>1$.  Hence $(x_n-2)^2>x_n-2$.  So $x_n-2>\sqrt{x_n-2}$.  And finally $x_n>2+\sqrt{n-2}=x_{n+1}$